# Comments on nominations (and other things) appear to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

(A real bug report this time!)

I commented on [Arda's nomination](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3#post-48998), and noticed that the input text box wasn't cleared like normal after the post was made.  I refreshed the page and verified the box was clear, then posted a test comment to see if it would happen again — which it did.  However, it also re-posted my original comment!

[image: screenshot]

No one (mods and myself included) can delete them, flag them, or vote on them (though somehow [Anna's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election#comment-70814) got an upvote).  Clicking to open the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ doesn't work while on the election page, nor does clicking on the arrow by one's username or hovering over the username.  JavaScript issues?

Sorry for cluttering your nomination, Arda! :(

Comment: I can't flag or upvote them either.

Comment: It's because I'm *that* awesome.

Comment: Speaking of the SuperDropdown, the arrow by my name doesn't work on that page either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has, indeed, [been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120777/eeek-i-cant-upvote-comments-to-nominations-in-the-ask-ubuntu-election).

Blaming [Jarrod Dixon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/6/jarrod-dixon) may commence at any time.

Comment: Thanks for posting that link, I have been trying unsuccessfully for a few minutes.  I think the deploy might have a couple kinks remaining.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about :P

Comment: Jarrod? It's _clearly_ rchern's fault.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be fixed for me right now, I tried it in two different browsers but I cannot upvote any comments in the election.

Comment: @Fabian It's working fine for me. Have you tried refreshing the page/clearing your cache?

Comment: I cleared the cache and restarted Chrome, I also tried it in Firefox and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Jarrod Halp? (See Fabian's comments)

Comment: Yeah, it's not fixed for me either. FWIW: Firefox 9.0.1, Chrome, Amsterdam [CDN datacenter](http://debug-02.netdna-cdn.com/).

Comment: There are still complaints on other sites which seems to imply that the issue remains. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120839/unable-to-flag-or-vote-on-comments-on-moderator-nominations, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2420/cannot-edit-comments-to-nominees-in-the-election and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2421/posted-comments-to-nominees-also-appears-in-text-area-for-entering-comments.

Comment: The Amsterdam CDN node is having some issues and serving an older version of the file (ie, pre-bug-fix).  We've contacted their support and hope this resolves soon.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that the JavaScript totally broke down because:

> Uncaught Error: getQuestionId could not find an id